# Block html page from direct access but viewable from link?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

OK, so basically I've put together a very low security log in page (javascript username and passwords) which isn't a big deal cause there isn't really anything it's protecting, I just made a login page for the youth on my church website to view and study Sunday School material. What I'm wanting is to make it so you can't type in the direct html to your "profile" or bookmark it, I want them to have to use the javascript log in. For example, the script will direct bob to his "profile" at bob.html, but I want to only go to bob.html only if it comes from login.html, is there any way to do this without getting extremely complicated? I'm expecting there isn't but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no server side programming is involved you will have to use a simple JavaScript redirection which is not even considered as a "low-level" security but as a "non-level" security :)

Anyway you can check the referrer with document.referrer and redirect to the main page when its not correct, remember that this is very easy to manipulate by the user.

More details on document.referrer can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

if ((document.referrer).indexOf('login.html') > 0 && username=='someone' && password=='pass') {do stuff} else {user did not arrive from login.html or username is wrong or password is wrong}

Answer (score 0):

If this is all from client-side javascript, then you can't do anything that's real security.  I'm assuming you know that.

But, you can create a slight obstacle to direct access for the casual viewer by having the link from the login page set a very short expiration cookie (like 1-5 minutes), then go to the profile page and have the profile page have all the profile content hidden by default (via a CSS rule).  Then, your javascript can check to see if the cookie is present upon loading and, if so, show the content.

If the viewer tries to go directly to the profile page, the cookie will not exist and the page content will not get shown by the javascript.   Obviously, the content is still present in the page so any viewer with any knowledge of how web pages work could still see the content in other ways, but it wouldn't show by default in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple schemes are possible, like the one presented above by jfriend00.

You can also use rolling URLs.

Say your profile page is at http://example.com/profile/foo. Change it to http://example.com/profile/foo?time=yyMMddhhmm where yyMMdd represents the current date, and hhmm represents the current server time. Then make sure that the server refuses to serve this page if the time doesn't match.

Easy to see what happens if someone bookmarks this link. Their bookmark will work for at most one minute.

Unfortunately, the link on the page also expires in one minute. You can solve this problem that updates the URL roughly every minute, but it is not as straightforward as it may look. You will need to take into account the fact that the time on the user's computer may be different from the server time.

Another way to do it is with a [session cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie). Session cookies are good until the browser is closed. They expire automatically when you close it. This is a variant of jfriend00's original answer.

Hope this helps.